# Java Inheritance: How to declare a static variable in Super and instantiate it in subclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

How would you declare a static variable in Super and instantiate it in subclass

Example

```
class A
{
  static Queue<String> myArray;

  public void doStuff()
  {
     myArray.add(someMethod.getStuff());
  } 

}
class B extends A
{
  myArray = new LinkedList<String>();

}

class C extends A
{
  myArray = new LinkedList<String>();

}
```

Obviously this doesnt work. But how would you go about declaring a variable; then doing some common functionality with the variable in the super class; Then making sure each subclass gets it own static LinkedList?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What problem would this solve?

Comment: I want to have common functionality of array manipulation and have each subclass have its own static array. Therefore there will be two static arrays in total

Comment: In fact your first method itself will not compile. You are using static arrayList in non-static method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you have subclass-specific properties to manipulate, you can't do it in the superclass, and it is not logical to do it anyways. As was already mentioned, you can do something like this:

```
abstract class A {
      public abstract void doStuff();       
    }

class B extends A    {
  static List<String>myArray = new LinkedList<String>();

  public abstract void doStuff() {
      // do B stuff
  }

}

class C extends A  {
  static List<String>myArray = new LinkedList<String>();
  public abstract void doStuff() {
      // do C stuff
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do stuff along these lines.  The closest you can do is to have an abstract (non-static) method in the superclass and do some stuff with it.

But in general, you cannot force subclasses to do *anything* static, and you cannot access subclasses' static fields from a superclass like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`Static variable` is bound to a class rather than an instance. If you need a separate static variable for subclasses, you need to declare them in each of your subclasses.